# High school programmed instuctions book.

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for books like this physics book below. Basically a programmed set of exercises that teaches chunks of mathematics. Have you every seen things like that?

https://archive.org/details/vectorsprojec00fjam/page/n17/mode/2up

https://archive.org/details/projectphysicscollection&morf=-subject?tab=about

[image: https://archive.org/details/vectorsprojec00fjam/page/n17/mode/2up]

Comment: "Moore method" is a related phrase and [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/12709/28209) is very similar to your question.